# AttributeError when I return class

Tags: json, python-3.x, attributeerror, sanic

I'm using **sanic** for my API, and peewe as ORM.

and I wanna create helper for json response, but I got the error

`AttributeError: 'JsonResponse' object has no attribute 'all_records'`

`get` method in controller

```
from sanic.response import json
from sanic.views import HTTPMethodView

from models.project import Project
from helpers.json import JsonResponse


class ProjectListResource(HTTPMethodView):
    def get(self, resp):
        projects = Project().select().dicts()
        return JsonResponse(projects, all_records=True)
```

and my `helper` class

```
from sanic.response import json


class JsonResponse:
    def __init__(self, model, all_records=None):
        self.model = self._model_query(model)
        self.all_records = all_records

    def _model_query(self, model):
        if self.all_records:
            records = json({model: list(model)})
        else:
            records = {}

        return records
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I needed first initialize `all_records` variable.

```
def __init__(self, model, all_records=None):
        self.all_records = all_records
        self.model = self._model_query(model)
```